# Compare two ISO 8601 in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to right a function that would compare two ISO 6801 time stamps and return the most recent one. I'm having trouble figuring out an easy way to create a function

For example Given `string s1 = 2012-10-10 09:42:00;`  and `string s2 = 2012-10-10 09:52:00;`

compare_timestamp(s1,s2) would return s2

Comment: ISO 8601 is designed so that you can just compare the strings lexicographically (e.g. via `strcmp`) to determine their order in time.

Comment: @Nemo so convert both of `std::string`'s to `const char*` then use `strcmp`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you juste need to find the more recent, a string comparison is sufficent.

```
string &compare_timestamp(string &s1, string &s2) {
    return s1.compare(s2) > 0 ? s1 : s2;
}
```

Comment: I have to downvote this for not being as straightforward as it could be.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::string & compare_timestamp(std::string & lhs, std::string & rhs) {
    return std::max(lhs, rhs);
}
std::string const & compare_timestamp(std::string const & lhs, std::string const & rhs) {
    return std::max(lhs, rhs);
}
```

Now, a better solution would be to create a `TimeStamp` class rather than working with a `std::string` directly. The `TimeStamp` could internally hold a `std::string` and overload `operator<` to just defer to `std::string::operator<`, but you would be using [strong types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963019/how-to-learn-proper-c/11926698#11926698)